# Stop IzPack running ProcessPanel scripts with elevated privileges

Tags: java, root, privileges, izpack

I have an installer built with IzPack that uses run-privileged, which launches a shell script via ProcessPanel to generate some additional files.  The problem is that, at least on OSX, these files are being created as root and not the current user and subsequently can't be run by the non privileged user later on.

Is it possible in IzPack to run processes from ProcessPanel without elevated privileges but still retain the ability to install in /Applications?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a `.sh` file that is marked `<executable>` and set to run at `stage="postinstall"` that will set the permissions and users correctly. This way you have full control on what can (and cannot) be run as a specific user.